# Java - Does Around advice stop execution

Tags: java, aspectj

So, I am writing a logging service and our team has decided that we should display a model that displays both a before and an after of an updating service. Basically, it goes like this:

```
public class Appointment {
//Do some stuff
}

public class UpdateAppointmentLog {
    private Appointment oldAppointment;
    private Appointment newAppointment;
    //Do some other stuff
}
```

Since this is a logging service, I need to retrieve the old appointment before the update is applied and I want to get the new appointment after the update is applied, hence, I'm using an around advice to achieve this. However, I was pointed out that it might bring problems if this advice messes the execution of the update service.

Can the around advice stop/slow the method if a problem arises?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you put into the advice. If you just call some getter and write the result to the log, it cannot harm your main method.

It is not clear what you mean by "stop/slow the method". In the advice you can put the codes that will be called before your method and after your method. If this code is not slow, then don't need to worry about performance.

What *may* be important is when you do weaving: at the compile time or at run time. It depends on how many classes and methods you have in your application and for how many of them the advice is applicable. If you have 10 000 classes each with 10 methods, then in case of run time weaving there *might* be some delay when the application is starting up (depending on your case, it may be several seconds or more, just test it). In case you have 100 classes, very probably you will not even notice a difference.

In case you use compile time weaving, aspects will not affect start up time at all, no matter how many classes you have, 100 or 10 000.